# Contain ou join?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    $contacts = $this->Contact->find('all', array(
        'limit' => 20,
        'contain' => array('Address', 'Phone' => array('fields' => 'Phone.phone' ), 'Campaign'),
        'conditions' => array('Contact.campaign_id is not null', $conditions_leads),
        'order' => array('Contact.created' => 'DESC')
        ));
```

Ele me traz o seguinte array:

```
    array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Contact' => array(
        'id' => '24136',
        'source_contacts_id' => null,
        'user_id' => '1',
        'campaign_id' => '62',
        'name' => 'teste PECCIN',
        'document' => null,
        'email' => 'teste@HOTMAIL.COM',
        'gender' => null,
        'birthday_date' => null,
        'observation' => null,
        'contacted' => '0',
        'scheduled' => '0',
        'invalid_reg' => '0',
        'is_active' => '1',
        'import_id' => '19',
        'dropout_date' => null,
        'interested_course' => 'DIREITO',
        'parents' => null,
        'lead_contacted_date' => null,
        'created' => '2014-12-04 16:52:51',
        'modified' => '2014-12-04 16:52:51'
    ),
    'Campaign' => array(
        'id' => '62',
        'name' => 'LEADS - Colégio Estadual Julio De Castilhos',
        'enrollment_type' => '1',
        'campaign_type' => '1',
        'campaign_degree' => '1',
        'close_campaign' => '0',
        'campaign_entity' => '2',
        'import_key' => null,
        'created' => '2014-12-04 16:16:33',
        'modified' => '2014-12-04 16:16:33'
    ),
    'Address' => array(),
    'Phone' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'phone' => '51111111',
            'contact_id' => '24136'
        )
    )
)
```

)

Eu tenho uma condition que verifica se o e-mail ou telefones já estão cadastrados no sistema:

```
    $conditions_leads['OR'] = array(
        'Contact.email =' =>  $searchEmail, 
        'Phone.phone =' => $searchTelefone1,
        'Phone.phone =' => $searchTelefone2,
        );
```

Com o email funciona, mais quando coloco o Phone.phone da o seguinte erro:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Phone.phone' in 'where clause'
```

Query do SQL:

```
SELECT

    `Contact`.`id`, `Contact`.`source_contacts_id`, `Contact`.`user_id`,
    `Contact`.`campaign_id`, `Contact`.`name`, `Contact`.`document`,
    `Contact`.`email`, `Contact`.`gender`, `Contact`.`birthday_date`,
    `Contact`.`observation`, `Contact`.`contacted`, `Contact`.`scheduled`,
    `Contact`.`invalid_reg`, `Contact`.`is_active`, `Contact`.`import_id`,
    `Contact`.`dropout_date`, `Contact`.`interested_course`,
    `Contact`.`parents`, `Contact`.`lead_contacted_date`, `Contact`.`created`,
    `Contact`.`modified`, `Campaign`.`id`, `Campaign`.`name`, `Campaign`.`enrollment_type`,
    `Campaign`.`campaign_type`, `Campaign`.`campaign_degree`, `Campaign`.`close_campaign`,
    `Campaign`.`campaign_entity`, `Campaign`.`import_key`, `Campaign`.`created`,
    `Campaign`.`modified`

FROM

     `ipa`.`contacts` AS `Contact`

LEFT JOIN

    `ipa`.`campaigns` AS `Campaign` ON (`Contact`.`campaign_id` = `Campaign`.`id`)

WHERE

    `Contact`.`campaign_id` is not null AND (
        (`Contact`.`email` = 'teste@HOTMAIL.COM') OR (`Phone`.`phone` IS NULL)
    )

ORDER BY `Contact`.`created` DESC LIMIT 20
```

Alguém aí saberia me dizer o por que desse erro ou eu devo fazer de outra forma?

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro diz que a coluna `Phone.phone` é desconhecida.

Na linha `FROM`, essa tabela não é citada.

Comment: Como eu cito ele na linha FROM?

Comment: Faça algo como: `FROM 'Phone' <resto> WHERE 'Phone'.'phone'`.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer usando join:

```
    $contacts = $this->Contact->find('all', array(
        // 'fields' => array('campaign_id'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Contact.campaign_id is not NULL',
            $conditions_search
        ),
        'contain' => array('Campaign'),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'phones',
                'alias' => 'Phone',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array('Contact.id = Phone.contact_id'),                         
            )      
        )
    ));
```